# How to customize JSON output on the first level ONLY using JavaScript's stringify() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I use stringify() method in JavaScript to convert a list of objects to a string, but I need to customize the output on the first level **ONLY** like the following:

```js
[
  /*T01*/ {"startX":55,"endX":109,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
  /*T02*/ {"startX":110,"endX":164,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
  /*T03*/ {"startX":165,"endX":219,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
  /*T04*/ {"startX":220,"endX":274,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
  /*T05*/ {"startX":275,"endX":329,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
  /*T06*/ {"startX":330,"endX":384,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
  /*T07*/ {"startX":385,"endX":439,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
  /*T08*/ {"startX":440,"endX":494,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
  /*T09*/ {"startX":495,"endX":549,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
  /*T10*/ {"startX":550,"endX":604,"sartY":0,"endY":249}
]
```

Now there are other parameters in stringfy() method, replacer and space, can't I use them to format my output like the aforementioned format including:

- tabs
- spaces
- comments

Comment: Last time I checked, comments are not valid in JSON.

Comment: Also, your array structure starts with `{` not `[`

Comment: @epascarello I need comments so when I modify an item later, I do it quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to get JSON.parse to make that output since it is not valid JSON. But if you want to have something rendered like that, it is a simple loop and string concatenation.

```js
var details = [
    {"startX":55,"endX":109,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
    {"startX":110,"endX":164,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
    {"startX":165,"endX":219,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
    {"startX":220,"endX":274,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
    {"startX":275,"endX":329,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
    {"startX":330,"endX":384,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
    {"startX":385,"endX":439,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
    {"startX":440,"endX":494,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
    {"startX":495,"endX":549,"sartY":0,"endY":249},
    {"startX":550,"endX":604,"sartY":0,"endY":249}
];

var out = "[\n" + details.map(function(val, i) {
  var id = "\t/*T" + ("0" + (i + 1)).substr(-2) + "*/\t";
  return id + JSON.stringify(val);
}).join(",\n") + "\n]";
console.log(out);
```